# Не работает Docker после перезагрузки Pycharm

Tags: python, django, docker

Просто перезагрузил Pycharm и получил такой Event Log:

```
Couldn't refresh skeletons for remote interpreter
            Failed to get an effective user for the Docker Compose service:
            Process `docker-compose config` failed.
            exec: "docker": executable file not found in $PATH
            Current PATH : /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/PycharmProjects/pythonlearn/venv/bin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
            Regenerate skeletons
```

перестал работать Docker, на `docker ps`, пишет: `bash: docker: command not found`

Работаю с Django и Docker, покажу файлы которые потребуются, кто сталкивался или видел похожее, буду рад любой помощи

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего твой Pycharm запускает проект со своим ENV в котором в PATH нет каталога в котором лежит бинарник docker.
Видно что сейчас path вот такой

```
Current PATH : /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/PycharmProjects/pythonlearn/venv/bin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

Попробуй выполни не в терминале pychatm команду whereis docker, так ты узнаешь где лежит бинарник докера.
Потом добавь его в переменную PATH в настройках твоего окружения.

Comment: Иван Глазков, `whereis` у меня ничего не выводит, у меня mac, whereis = which в mac, поэтому я написал `which docker` и опять же ничего в ответ не получил